# Unity: text is clear in editor but blurry in game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've read that Unity has problems rendering clear text and I've tried out several different fixes: setting a large font size on the imported font and changing the character setting to unicode, making the text size large and then scaling it down, setting filter mode to point when it comes to pixel fonts... All these methods seem to work from the editor (as in, the text appears crisp), but in the game the text is still blurry:

[image: editor view]

vs.

[image: game view]

(The screenshot is using free aspect - the text looks better, but still somewhat blurry, when the game view resolution matches the reference resolution.)

Currently, the imported font (not pixel) is set to a size of 180; rendering to smooth; character to unicode. The text isn't scaled right now and is at a size of 50. The canvas is set to scale with screen size, and the reference resolution is 2560x1440 (a Samsung S7). It should also be noted that at a different resolution, the box around the text (which is an image) also gets blurry, which makes me think it's a problem with the canvas scaling.

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried messing with `pixels per unit `

Comment: Also, scaling the text *up* causes it to display the pixels at a larger size, with very little inter-pixel smoothing. I almost always scale my text *down.*

Comment: @mad.meesh it doesn't appear to make a difference...

Comment: @Draco18s the font size is set to be large, but the text element itself is scaled down (at least when I was experimenting with that method). In all cases, the text looked fine in the editor (even when zooming in) but got blurry in the actual game.

Comment: Would you mind showing a *not zoomed* image from your game view? And the same spot, with closely matching zoom, from, the scene view?

Comment: @Draco18s updated!

Comment: Ok, wow, that's really bad. Check: pixel perfect (canvas setting). Check if any parents of the text are scaled (unlikely). Can't think of anything else.

Comment: @Draco18s pixel perfect provides a marginal improvement, but still blurred; the canvas is scaled, but that seems to be automatic (I can't manually change the scale).

Comment: Canvas scale should not be controlled automatically. I can fiddle with a canvas scale's values myself with expected results.

Comment: @Draco18s it seems it's that way because the canvas mode is set to overlay. If I change it to world space, the RectTransform becomes editable (but then nothing appears in the game view). Then if I change it back, the canvas becomes unscaled...though there's no apparent difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was uncheck `Low Resolution Aspect Ratios` in the game view... The text is still slightly blurry, but likely that's typical of Unity. To counter that, I just decided to use a pixel font (using the fix explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccYJOT7bUUY)).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Unity UI.Text Blurry Fix]

I use scaling down as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was using Unity-Remote. After building the app directly I didn't see the blur anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the best solution to the blurry text problem in Unity is as follows:

1. Select the text item from the scene.
2. Go to Font and see where your font is located in your project folder
3. Go to your font in your project
4. Change the font size from 16 to 100-300
5. change "Character" to "Unicode"
6. Press Apply

[image]